# Django m2m_changed not triggered with a custom through model

Tags: django, m2m

```
class SparePart(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

class SparePartOrderRelation(models.Model):
    sparepart = models.ForeignKey(SparePart)
    order = models.ForeignKey('SparePartOrder')

class SparePartOrder(models.Model):
    spareparts = models.ManyToManyField(SparePart, through=SparePartOrderRelation)

def signaltest(**kwargs):
    print kwargs['action']

m2m_changed.connect(signaltest, sender=SparePartOrder.spareparts.through, weak=False, dispatch_uid='signaltest')
```

(simplified models for clarity)

Why isn't the `m2m_changed` signal send and `signaltest` called? when I save a `SparePartOrder`?
I've tried replacing the `sender=` with almost every combination of (possible) references to the m2m model (`SparePartOrder.spareparts`, `SparePartOrderRelation` etc.)

Help is appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: How about chaning the signature to `def signaltest(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):` ?

Comment: @karthikr unfortunately, doesn't change anything. Is there a way to debug Django signals?

Comment: Its funny you ask - I am debugging a django-signal i am facing in my code as we speak :) I use `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()` and navigate step by step.